# In app purchases crashing app when changing scenes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I've implemented in app purchases into my shop scene for my game and have been having problems when changing from the shop scene to another scene it seems to crash the game and gives me this error

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x840f8010)
```

Or it gives me a multiple version of other errors such as:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x3f8)
```

it also sometimes gives me an error that changes lines in the subclass like so

[image]

When I comment out the code in the subclass that searches for the app purchase information or put the phone into airplane mode it works fine and the problem is gone.

I have a subclass of SKnode that gets the information on the purchasable items and then displays it through the use of SKLabels and sprite nodes to display a picture of the purchase in the shop as seen below:

```
class InAppPurchaseItems: SKNode, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

var shopItemNode = SKSpriteNode()
var itemPriceBackground = SKSpriteNode()
var shopItemLabel = SKLabelNode()
var shopItemTitleLabel = SKLabelNode()
var pressableNode = SKSpriteNode()
var itemPriceLabel = SKLabelNode()

var title: String = ""
var information: String = ""
var image: String = ""

var price:String = "X"

func createAppPurchaseItem(ID: String, purchaseImage: String, purchaseTitle:String) {

    title = purchaseTitle
    image = purchaseImage

    createTheNode()

    //let product = SKProduct()
    let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: ID)  //"RedShield.Astrum.Purchase", "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase")
    let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
    request.delegate = self as? SKProductsRequestDelegate
    request.start()
}

public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request...")
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")

        if product.productIdentifier == "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            information = product.localizedDescription

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            information = product.localizedDescription

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "1500Stars.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTeirOne")

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "7500Stars.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTeirTwo")

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "14000Stars.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTeirThree")

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "28000Stars.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTeirFour")

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "65000Stars.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTeirFive")

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "128000Stars.Astrum.Purchase" {

            price = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
            shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTeirSix")

        }

         createShopLabels()
    }
}

func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
    let price = item.price
    if price == 0 {
        return "GET" //or whatever you like
    } else {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        let locale = item.priceLocale
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.locale = locale
        return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
    }
}

func createTheNode() {

    let tex:SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: image)

    shopItemNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex, color: SKColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 85, height: 85)) //frame.maxX / 20, height: frame.maxY / 20))
    shopItemNode.zPosition = -10
    shopItemNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 35)

    self.addChild(shopItemNode)
    self.name = "ShopItem"
    self.zPosition = -11

    shopItemTitleLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Avenir-Black")
    shopItemTitleLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black;
    shopItemTitleLabel.fontSize = 15 //self.frame.maxY/30
    shopItemTitleLabel.position = CGPoint (x: 0, y: -30)
    shopItemTitleLabel.text = "\(title)"
    shopItemTitleLabel.zPosition = -9
    self.addChild(shopItemTitleLabel)

    itemPriceBackground = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "PriceShopBackground"), color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: 80, height: 30)) //SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 65, height: 20))
    //itemPriceBackground.alpha = 0.4
    itemPriceBackground.zPosition = -10
    itemPriceBackground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -54)
    addChild(itemPriceBackground)

    pressableNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 140))
    pressableNode.zPosition = -7
    pressableNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    shopItemSprites.append(pressableNode)
    addChild(pressableNode)

}

func createShopLabels() {

    shopItemLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Avenir-Black")
    shopItemLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white;
    shopItemLabel.fontSize = 15 //self.frame.maxY/30
    shopItemLabel.position = CGPoint (x: 0, y: -60)
    shopItemLabel.text = "\(price)"
    shopItemLabel.zPosition = -9
    addChild(shopItemLabel)

 }

}
```

they're then displayed on the store scene with the following code:

```
 let ShopItem = InAppPurchaseItems()
 ShopItem.createAppPurchaseItem(ID: "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase", purchaseImage: "2StarCoin", purchaseTitle: "+2 In Game Pickups")
 ShopItem.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX / 1.6, y: self.frame.midY * 0.8)
 ShopItem.zPosition = 100
 ShopItem.name = "Shp0"
 moveableArea.addChild(ShopItem)
```

**Shop's Main Class**

The shops main class also has in app purchase code that is used for buying the product and also to be able to search for the product information just like in the subclass as seen below

```
class ShopItemMenu: SKScene, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

//Purchase Variables
var listOfProducts = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

override func didMoveToView(to view: SKView) {

 let ShopItem = InAppPurchaseItems()
 ShopItem.createAppPurchaseItem(ID: "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase", purchaseImage: "2StarCoin", purchaseTitle: "+2 In Game Pickups")
 ShopItem.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX / 1.6, y: self.frame.midY * 0.8)
 ShopItem.zPosition = 100
 ShopItem.name = "Shp0"
 moveableArea.addChild(ShopItem)

}


//This function allows for a product to be bought buy the user and starts the proccess for purchasing
func appPurchaseBuying(appPurchaseID:String) {
    for product in listOfProducts {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == appPurchaseID) {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
        }
    }
}

//This Function restores all previously purchased Items (use this for the restor button.
func restorePurchasesOfItems() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}


//This function checks if they can make payments and then loads the product ids from a harcoded set. (use this to start when the scene starts)
func checkCanMakePayment() {
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("can make payments...")
        let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase", "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "In-App Purchases Not Enabled", message: "Please enable In App Purchases in Settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
            if url != nil
            {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
            }

        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        if let vc = self.scene?.view?.window?.rootViewController {
            vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

//This allows the user to buy the product with a product idetifier given by the variable "p"
func buyProduct() {
    print("buying " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
}

//This Function gets all the avaliable products from apple and puts them into the product Array called listOfProducts
public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
   /* print("product request...")
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")

        if product.productIdentifier == "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase" {

            shieldPurchasePrice = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!

        } else if product.productIdentifier == "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase" {

            DoubleCoinPurchasePrice = priceStringForProduct(item: product)!
        }

      /*print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)
     */
        listOfProducts.append(product)
    }*/
}




func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
    let price = item.price
    if price == 0 {
        return "GET" //or whatever you like
    } else {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        let locale = item.priceLocale
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.locale = locale
        return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
    }
}



    //This Function restores all the already purchased products so that things can be restored such as shield
    public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("restoring all...")
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase":
            isRedShieldPurchaseOn = true

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(isRedShieldPurchaseOn, forKey: "shieldPurchase")
            print("finished restoring this purchase")

        case "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase":
            isCoinPurchaseOn = true

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(isCoinPurchaseOn, forKey: "doubleCoinPurchase")
            print("finished restoring this purchase")

        default:
            print("IAP not found")
        }
    }

    alert(title: "Restored", msg: "Purchases were restored")
}

//This Function is run when the user makes a purchase and checks the state of the purchase to make sure it works
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("adding payment...")

    for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            print("buying ok, Unlocking purchase...")
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier
            switch prodID {

                case "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase":
                    isRedShieldPurchaseOn = true

                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.set(isRedShieldPurchaseOn, forKey: "shieldPurchase")
                    print("unlocked Purchase")

                case "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase":
                    isCoinPurchaseOn = true

                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.set(isCoinPurchaseOn, forKey: "doubleCoinPurchase")
                    print("unlocked Purchase")

                case "SOME IN APP PURCHASE ID HERE":
                    print("unlocked Purchase")

                default:
                    print("IAP Not found")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)

        case .failed:
            print("error with payment...")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)

        default:
            print("Default")
        }
    }
}
```

**Am I going about doing this the right way or is there a better way to do this and how can I fix the crashing issue i'm having?**

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

[image]

**EDIT 3**

[image]

**EDIT 4**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import StoreKit

class PurchaseService {

static let session = PurchaseService()
var products = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()



//This function allows for a product to be bought buy the user and starts the proccess for purchasing
func appPurchaseBuying(appPurchaseID:String) {
    for product in products {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == appPurchaseID) {
            p = product
            buyProduct()
        }
    }
}

//This Function restores all previously purchased Items (use this for the restor button.
func restorePurchasesOfItems() {
    //SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}


//This function checks if they can make payments and then loads the product ids from a harcoded set. (use this to start when the scene starts)
func checkCanMakePayment() {
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("can make payments...")
        let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase", "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        //request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "In-App Purchases Not Enabled", message: "Please enable In App Purchases in Settings", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

            let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)
            if url != nil
            {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
            }

        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
    }
}

//This allows the user to buy the product with a product idetifier given by the variable "p"
func buyProduct() {
    print("buying " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    //SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay as SKPayment)
}

//This Function gets all the avaliable products from apple and puts them into the product Array called listOfProducts
public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request...")
    let myProduct = response.products
    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")

        products.append(product)
    }
}




func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
    let price = item.price
    if price == 0 {
        return "GET" //or whatever you like
    } else {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        let locale = item.priceLocale
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        numberFormatter.locale = locale
        return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
    }
}



//This Function restores all the already purchased products so that things can be restored such as shield
public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("restoring all...")
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase":
            isRedShieldPurchaseOn = true

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(isRedShieldPurchaseOn, forKey: "shieldPurchase")
            print("finished restoring this purchase")

        case "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase":
            isCoinPurchaseOn = true

            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(isCoinPurchaseOn, forKey: "doubleCoinPurchase")
            print("finished restoring this purchase")

        default:
            print("IAP not found")
        }
    }

    //alert(title: "Restored", msg: "Purchases were restored")
}

//This Function is run when the user makes a purchase and checks the state of the purchase to make sure it works
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("adding payment...")

    for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .purchased:
            print("buying ok, Unlocking purchase...")
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier
            switch prodID {

            case "RedShield.Astrum.Purchase":
                isRedShieldPurchaseOn = true

                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(isRedShieldPurchaseOn, forKey: "shieldPurchase")
                print("unlocked Purchase")

            case "DoubleCoin.Astrum.Purchase":
                isCoinPurchaseOn = true

                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(isCoinPurchaseOn, forKey: "doubleCoinPurchase")
                print("unlocked Purchase")

            case "SOME IN APP PURCHASE ID HERE":
                print("unlocked Purchase")

            default:
                print("IAP Not found")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)

        case .failed:
            print("error with payment...")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)

        default:
            print("Default")
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this and I've been trying for hours to fix this but it just ends up giving me errors i know it has something to do with the app purchase request function i have in the subclass but i can't seem to fix it. Does anyone have ideas on what to do?

Comment: @matt still new to xcode, where do i find the crash log? my app isn't deployed yet its just running on simulators and my own phone at the moment and all i can find is how to show a crash report for deployed apps

Comment: @matt I updated my post with the console from when it crashed it doesn't tell much expect for the fact it occurred somewhere when the purchase items where being loaded. i'll look into the zombie thing and get back to you because it seems to change between errors whenever it crashes sometimes its the label that shows the price that gets the error and sometimes its something else. I know it occurs somewhere in the subclass of the InAppPurchase class but i can't seem to find away to fix it

Comment: That is not the crash log, unfortunately

Comment: @matt so its not what you wanted to see where else can i find it? Also i profiled my app and ran the zombies tool and found this when it crashed (see Edit 2 in my post) i just don't know what do with that because i don't remember having objective C code in my project.

Comment: Brilliant, you’ve found it.

Comment: Unfortunately your screen shot is not scrollable. :) But if you scroll down it will show the later history of this object and you can see when it got released.

Comment: @matt I scrolled down and found the zombie but i'm not sure what to do next, any ideas?

Comment: @matt see my new edit in my post for details on the zombie

Comment: Hard to say. You've scrolled to a place where Instruments is no longer showing us what method each line represents. But I think we can be pretty sure that at some point Astrum mismanages memory and causes the retain count on this object to get too low. My guess is that you are mismanaging _threads_. You might be multithreaded in your handling of this object; that could cause this kind of issue.

Comment: So far so good. In this class you should not have any UI calls, those need to be in your view controller (like the alert in checkCanMakePayment). In your app delegate application function call  PurchaseService.session.checkCanMakePayment() thus starting the request. In func productsRequest you might skip the loop and just assign response.products to products since it is already [SKProduct]. Later on you can call PurchaseService.session to run your functions related to in-app purchases and since the class is a singleton (static) and the data remains persistent throughout the app.

Comment: I see what you mean, now when I do want to get the price for the in app purchase after i’ve Done the request when my app has launched, how do I filter through the products array to find the specific product and get its price? Do I do Purchase.session.products? And then what do I do after that?

Comment: The easiest way is to make a function inside PurchaseService say `func product(id productID:String)->SKProduct` and inside the function for loop to iterate through the products until you find the one with the identifier you want. If all you need is the price then you might make a `func price(for productID)->Double` that does the same thing but returns the price. Or even more convenient is returning the formatted price string with currency symbol.

Comment: thanks for that and helping me with everything and answering my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having all the StoreKit code in your game scene makes it more difficult to isolate the issue you're having. I'd suggest you make a new swift file let's call it PurchaseService with a static instance like this:

```
class PurchaseService {
      static let session = PurchaseService()
      var products = [SKProduct]()
      // code
}
```

You can implement all your purchasing related logic here. I usually use a getPurchases function to load the available purchases from the store and call it from the application function of the AppDelegate.swift file. This ensures that your purchases get loaded very early and will be ready the first moment you need them (because you make a static instance you can refer to it any time you need to do a purchase through PurchaseService.session...)

To get the prices you can use a function that iterates through your products variable and checks the product id:

```
func price(for productID:String)->Double{
  if products.count>0 {
  for product in products {
    if product.productIdentifier == productID {
      return product.price.doubleValue
    }
  }
 }
}
```

If you comply to the SKProductRequestDelegate protocol you don't need to conditionally cast self to it:

```
 // unnecessary:  request.delegate = self as? SKProductsRequestDelegate
    request.delegate = self
```

Wondering if you made the productRequest method public because by the time the request returns the SKProductResponse object self is no longer available.

Regarding Objective-C code in your project: I see you might be using Firebase (from your console messages I'm inferring) and it has some objective-c bits and pieces.

Comment: Ok, I think i'm confused, this my first time using Storekit and still trying to wrap my head around how to use it. so i request the products once the app loads, but how do I go about storing each products prices so I can display the local price later when the player loads up the store scene? because the way i'm doing it now (as you can see from the "InAppPurchase" subclass that i'm requesting the product every time it loads the store scene. could you please elaborate with more code on how I store the product's prices for use later and how I go about setting up this new swift file class.

Comment: Thanks again for your help its greatly appreciated. Also i'm not using firebase i don't have it installed so i'm still not sure what the objective C code is.

Comment: what you can do is create a var products: [SKProduct] and a you assign it the product array returned from the appstore (in the getPurchases function). To make things easier I usually create a helper function to deal with the pricing, see updated answer

Comment: Ok I see what you mean by adding in the SKProducts array and requesting the products and just searching that array for the product identifier that I specify. I’m still having trouble with creating the purchase session class that you mentioned and how I go about using it in my app delegate file. I have provided my class in EDIT 4 on my original post, could you please tell me if i’m On the right track and if you could please provide an example of the purchase service class, so I can get some idea on how to set it up. Sorry if this is an inconvenience i’m Just trying to set this up the right way.

Comment: I see what you mean, now when I do want to get the price for the in app purchase after i’ve Done the request when my app has launched, how do I filter through the products array to find the specific product and get its price? Do I do Purchase.session.products? And then what do I do after that?

Answer (score 1):

Stab in the dark here, but you've spelled `Tier` incorrectly in your image names... Any possibility it's crashing because no image exists with those names?

i.e. this line: `shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTeirSix")`

ought to be changed to: `shopItemNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "BuyStarsTierSix")`

If this isn't your issue I'd recommend you fix the asset names regardless, typos in names gets confusing.

Comment: Yeah I know its spelt wrong its just what I named the graphic file and i couldn't bothered changing it because i was sleep deprived at the time of naming it.

Comment: Understandable, has happened a few times to me, realize and can't be arsed to fix it. Was hoping I spotted an easy fix though haha.